# 2 line plot using seaborn

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

I want to plot this array. I am using seaborn to do that. I used

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
sns.kdeplot(data= score_for_modelA[:,0])
```

But the above one only gives for column 1. My scores are in column 1 and 2 and I want both of them plotted in the same graph.
The sample data is like this:
array ([[0.67,0.33],[0.45,0.55],......,[0.81,0.19]]

Comment: Hi @Ojjasvi Puri, please provide some sample data so it can be reproduced. Likely you need to change the way you are indexing "score_for_modelA".

Comment: @Horbaje score_for_modelA is an array like ([[0.67,0.33],[0.45,0.55],......,[0.81,0.19]]). I want to get these 2 columns in the same graph with different legends saying which line graph represents which one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting them into a data frame first, with the proper column names, for example:

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# create sample dataframe in wide format
score_for_modelA = np.random.normal(0, 1, (50, 2))
df = pd.DataFrame(score_for_modelA, columns=['col1', 'col2'])

# use melt to convert the dataframe to a long form
dfm = df.melt()
```

Plot the long form dataframe

```
sns.kdeplot(data=dfm, hue="variable", x="value")
```

[image]

As pointed out by @JohanC, if you want all of the columns:

```
sns.kdeplot(data=df)
```

Comment: If all the columns of a dataframe are plotted, `.melt()` isn't strictly necessary.  `sns.kdeplot(data=pd.DataFrame(A, columns=['col1', 'col2']))` also works well.

Comment: Oh thanks for pointing that out @JohanC, did not know that.